Captioning an average of image set
I'm looking for a captioning model that would be able to describe a group of images in a single sentence. Alternatively, I need a way to conceptually average a group of images before feeding that "concept" (presumably a feature vector) to a regular captioning model.
Why?
For Lora training evaluation. It would be useful to test the trained generation model on a prompt that would fit the dataset as a whole instead of selecting captions of single images or trying to find what's common among them. Moreover, this would also allow to produce a single negative prompt to test how model behaves on out of scope prompts.
What I've done so far:
I've modified an existing CLIP+BLIP interrogator to work with image sets (it can also produce negatives). However, while CLIP captioning allows averaging image features before using them to choose the best caption, it's far less accurate than captions produced by BLIP, which only works with single images. I need a model that would take in feature vectors like CLIP so I can preprocess them.

Hope the fifth time I'm asking this question would be the charm, I've tried all kinds of stackexchanges and I'm either ignored or closed without any hints even though I've done my research and even built a prototype, what else can I add?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'd like to speak to a human.

outline: have a model to turn each picture into a feature vector. have another model to ingest that set of feature vectors, and emit text.

see also: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/47010/captioning-an-average-of-image-set-instead-of-individial-pictures
